# Ruby - NameError: uninitialized constant when accessing name of my derived class

Tags: ruby, reflection

I have class B derived from class A, like:

```
class A
..
end

class B < A
...
end
```

In another file I defined a variable M

```
M = B
```

Then I got the error

```
"NameError: uninitialized constant B".
```

I just found that if I write

```
M=A
M=B
```

Then it's OK. It seems I have to initialize A in some way.

Comment: Why not go ahead and do it?

Comment: I use this as a temporary way. I just feel that's not natural. Ruby should have its own solution by its grammar, I guess.

Comment: That does not make any sense, what version of ruby are you using?
I just did the following in test.rb                                                                                                                   class A
end
class B < A
end  and then in IRB i required the file and did what you did and did not receive that error.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]<br>  They are in separate files. That may be the cause. How do I require the file in my code? BTW, it's a rails project, but my classes are in a separate file which has no relationship with rails.

Comment: You require files with `require`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the files have no relationship with rails lets assume that they are two seperate files on in any folder on your system. 
Assuming they are in the same directory.

class_def.rb:

```
class A
  def self.talk
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

class B < A
  def self.talk
    super()
    puts 'world'
  end
end
```

runner.rb:

```
require './class_def.rb'
M=B
M.talk
```

calling ruby runner.rb should produce the output

```
hello
world
```

However I noticed the same error using RubyFiddle

w/  a call to the method http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/1d8e2

w/o a call to the method http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/1d8e2/

Comment: The thing is both class A and B are in the same file, while I'm accessing them from another file. I can access A without this require statement, then why do I need this when accessing B?

Comment: How do you have access to A without requiring the file with the classes?  You must be doing something else you're not stating.

Comment: That's in a ruby project. I put my class definition file under the app/models directory and rails should automatically require this file. I have to emphasize that my class A is not a subclass of ActiveRecord. It's just independent.